# Access XML node by absolute path

Tags: python, xml

I'm parsing an xml file in Python 2.7.
I'm using the xml.etree.ElementTree module, working on OSX 10.10.
The file is very large and I would like to be able to access specific nodes in a reasonably efficient way.   If I know the absolute path for a node I can access it by continually using .find(), but surely there is an easier way.

For example, if the xml is

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

<A>
    <C>
    unwanted text
    </C>
    <B> 
        <C>
        wanted text
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

I can access 'wanted text' with `root.find("A").find("B").find("C").text` but that is obviously awkward.

Is there a better way?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findall` and xpath expressions, for example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = """
<A>
    <C>
    unwanted text
    </C>
    <B> 
        <C>
        wanted text
        </C>
    </B>
    <B> 
        <C>
        wanted text 2
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
"""

tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml))
c_nodes = tree.getroot().findall("B/C")

for c in c_nodes:
    print(c.text)
```

This will return all C elements childs of A and B and should be really fast.

You can see all the supported XPath operations here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't that clear, I don't want all "C" element texts, only the specific one with absolute path /A/B/C. I've edited the question to emphasis that more.

Answer (score 0):

For a very large xml file you would probably use `iterparse`, to avoid reading the entire file into memory.

Here, `iterparse` watches for the close of each element, by default. Inside the for-loop, when the code notices a 'C' element it outputs its 'text' content.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

for ev, el in ElementTree.iterparse('ludog.xml'):
    if el.tag=='C':
        print (el.text)
```

**Edit in response to comment.**

I've extended your xml to this, to demonstrate the principle in the code that follows.

```
<more>
    <D>
        <C>
            other text
        </C>
    </D>
    <A>
        <B> 
            <C>
            text
            </C>
        </B>
    </A>
</more>
```

`iterparse` can be made to indicate both the start and end of an xml element. Here I use this to keep track of whether `iterparse` is currently parsing within an 'A' element or a 'B' element, or both. When it's inside both, and it encounters a 'C' element, the code emits the 'text' for the 'C' element.

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> inside_A = False
>>> inside_B = False
>>> for ev, el in ElementTree.iterparse('ludog.xml', events=('start', 'end')):
...     if el.tag=='A':
...         inside_A = ev=='start'
...     if el.tag=='B':
...         inside_B = ev=='start'
...     if el.tag=='C' and ev=='end' and inside_A and inside_B:
...         print(el.text)
... 

            text

>>>
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't that clear, I don't want all "C" element texts, only the specific one with absolute path /A/B/C. I've edited the question to emphasis that more.